# SQL Server 2012 Installation Hangs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-8

We have a Windows 8 machine that we installed SQL Server 2005 on first.

We then uninstalled it and installed SQL Server 2012 - unsuccessfully. The installation wizard hung at the point where it says:

```
SqlEngineDBStartConfigAction_install_configrc_Cpu64
```

The event log showed the following error:

```
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
WARNING: You have until SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) to logoff. If you have not logged off at this time, 
your session will be disconnected, and any open files or devices you have open may lose data.
```

We got the same error while trying to start the service.

We tried uninstalling and re-installing but faced the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

We tried installing it on a Windows 7 machine as well and faced the same problem.

Comment: For those wondering, SQL Server 2012 Standard on Windows 8 [is actually a supported OS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually an issue I had recently and after a tireless struggle (tried any solution the internet came up with) came to the conclusion that the installation file was corrupted in some manner. The original download was from Dreamworks if that matters, so I just downloaded a fresh install from Microsoft and it went beautifully.

Try that and post back if it works.....

Comment: We re-downloaded, tried again, and it worked.